# Catching a FK constraint violation error when trying to delete a record from a table that is a child in the hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple configuration,

```
CREATE TABLE dev.user (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (1024) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dev.schema (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES dev.user (id)
);

CREATE TABLE dev.schema_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    schema_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES dev.schema (id)
);
```

Basically, a `user` can own many `schema` records, and a `schema` record can have many `schema_table` records linked to it.

I am trying to delete a record from `dev.schema_table` and I'm catching an error,

```
update or delete on table "schema_table" violates
    foreign key constraint "schema_table_schema_id_fkey" on table "schema_table"
```

I'm a little confused, as to why I'm running into this error.

I first create 3 `schema_table` records with the same value for the field `schema_id` and then I try to delete one of these `schema_table` records.

What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this FK constraint violation error?

Comment: As an unrelated side note: the use of `serial` is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favor of the standard compliant `identity` columns

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but more a lengthy remark.

I tried to reproduce the issue:

```
tkdb=> create schema dev;
CREATE SCHEMA
tkdb=> CREATE TABLE dev.user (
tkdb(>     id serial PRIMARY KEY,
tkdb(>     name VARCHAR (1024) NOT NULL
tkdb(> );
CREATE TABLE
tkdb=> 
tkdb=> CREATE TABLE dev.schema (
tkdb(>     id serial PRIMARY KEY,
tkdb(>     user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES dev.user (id)
tkdb(> );
CREATE TABLE
tkdb=> 
tkdb=> CREATE TABLE dev.schema_table (
tkdb(>     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
tkdb(>     schema_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES dev.schema (id)
tkdb(> );
CREATE TABLE
tkdb=> insert into dev.user values (1, 'Hans');
INSERT 0 1
tkdb=> insert into dev.schema values (3, 1);
INSERT 0 1
tkdb=> insert into dev.schema_table values (10, 3);
INSERT 0 1
tkdb=> insert into dev.schema_table values (11, 3);
INSERT 0 1
tkdb=> insert into dev.schema_table values (12, 3);
INSERT 0 1
tkdb=> delete from dev.schema_table where id = 11;
DELETE 1
```

And as you can see from the output, it works!

What do you do differently?